# how to develop internet explorer add-on

Tags: internet-explorer, add-on, ieaddon

Can we create add-on for IE? If yes where can i find required resources/docs?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Some references,

- At MSDN blogs -- [**Writing IE AddOns**](http://blogs.msdn.com/petel/archive/2006/11/07/writing-ie-addons.aspx),
- The Business of Software [recent discussion](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?biz.5.736647.8)

[**A New IE Add-on Site**](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/04/25/583369.aspx) -- [reference](http://www.ieaddons.com/en/).

> The site has two objectives: to make it easier for users to find valuable add-ons and to promote our partners who develop add-ons.
>
> You can have your add-on included by submitting it through the Internet Explorer Add-on site and you no longer have to be a member of the Microsoft Partner program to be included.

---

[Add-on-CON](http://addoncon.com/blog/) blog.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Microsoft's SpicIE which wraps all the com features of IE, so you can simply develop your own extensions (toolbars, context menu items, etc) using managed code (such as c#, vb.net)

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SpicIE

Answer (score 2):

You can just develop a Google Chrome extension (easy peasy Japanesey and great documentation) and use the Google Chrome "IE Tab" extension to test IE functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good reference from Eric Law (Microsoft) in the different ways to develop Internet Explorer add-ons. Be sure to install the IEToys linked in the post to see some DHTML examples with source code.

**Powering up with Internet Explorer Extensibility:**
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2005/09/06/461675.aspx

**Enhance IE Add-on Development:**
http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/dev.asp

**IEToys:**
http://www.bayden.com/ietoys/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering about this in 2018 or later, they don't really have a way to upload your extension to ie11. You can make one for Edge though.