# Internet Explorer Accelerator - Open default browser

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, accelerator

We built an accelerator that allows users to right click on a clientID in an old ERP system (IE only), and it opens our new system in a new tab, on the client with that Old_ClientID

I'm wondering tough, is it possible to configure accelerators (in the accelerator XML or in the browser settings) so that accelerated links open in chrome/firefox/... or whatever the default browser is?

The new system contains a lot of google maps stuff that just works a  lot faster in chrome, and users are complaining that they are AGAIN bound to IE(8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue:** The [Internet Explorer Accelerator feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc289775(v=vs.85).aspx) takes some user selected content and using the accelerator XML definition, constructs a URI that Internet Explorer will navigate to, or optionally display in a preview window. Like following normal links in the browser there's no way to have that link open in a different browser.

**Workaround**: [Create an Internet Explorer plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237078/how-to-develop-internet-explorer-add-on?rq=1) to open the current page in the user's default browser. Your users can use this plugin to open whatever page they like in their default browser.

Comment: I'll accept this answer because the workaround makes sense, but know that I did not actually test this. (since this problem was dated 2013, and I don't work on this accelerator anymore)